Finding URL with Selenium not printing correctly
I'm trying to compile a list of links within a page. However, when printing the list the output is a bunch of random numbers
links = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "meta[content*='www.airbnb.com.au/rooms/']")

print(links)

Example output:
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="faf70ce53ba59d6f6995883b0edfc006", element="f.CD9BA18B85DC3350F27BC5BF71FF60B2.d.5C798985F0B6BFD4214898A37DFC2A30.e.81")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="faf70ce53ba59d6f6995883b0edfc006", element="f.CD9BA18B85DC3350F27BC5BF71FF60B2.d.5C798985F0B6BFD4214898A37DFC2A30.e.82")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="faf70ce53ba59d6f6995883b0edfc006", element="f.CD9BA18B85DC3350F27BC5BF71FF60B2.d.5C798985F0B6BFD4214898A37DFC2A30.e.83")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="faf70ce53ba59d6f6995883b0edfc006", element="f.CD9BA18B85DC3350F27BC5BF71FF60B2.d.5C798985F0B6BFD4214898A37DFC2A30.e.84")>]

The website im trying to scrape:
https://www.airbnb.com.au/s/Gold-Coast--QLD/homes?place_id=ChIJt2BdK0cakWsRcK_e81qjAgM&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&checkin=2024-12-22&checkout=2024-12-28&date_picker_type=calendar&adults=9&children=2&pets=1&search_type=user_map_move&tab_id=home_tab&query=Gold%20Coast%2C%20QLD&flexible_trip_lengths%5B%5D=one_week&monthly_start_date=2024-08-01&monthly_length=3&monthly_end_date=2024-11-01&search_mode=regular_search&price_filter_input_type=2&price_filter_num_nights=6&channel=EXPLORE&ne_lat=-27.8312213554841&ne_lng=153.85466017727208&sw_lat=-28.314709414353157&sw_lng=153.3574718233147&zoom=10.257561001998951&zoom_level=10.257561001998951&search_by_map=true&price_min=8683&price_max=14459&min_bedrooms=5

Those are not random numbers but the reference of the HTML element that points to those meta tags. You should iterate over the list and use the get_attribute("content") function to display the links captured

print(links)

You are just printing the list object which has web elements. To get the URLs from the target elements, you should capture the content attribute's value.
Try this:
for link in links:
    print(link.get_attribute("content"))

Output:
www.airbnb.com.au/rooms/50961691?adults=9&children=2&pets=1&search_mode=regular_search&check_in=2024-12-22&check_out=2024-12-28&source_impression_id=p3_1720094600_P3E3TFbSLV_F8Hv-&previous_page_section_name=1000
www.airbnb.com.au/rooms/10732858?adults=9&children=2&pets=1&search_mode=regular_search&check_in=2024-12-22&check_out=2024-12-28&source_impression_id=p3_1720094600_P3xqAumg9A_T_K_Z&previous_page_section_name=1000
www.airbnb.com.au/rooms/25083963?adults=9&children=2&pets=1&search_mode=regular_search&check_in=2024-12-22&check_out=2024-12-28&source_impression_id=p3_1720094600_P3LxjqyKDwEQn8FV&previous_page_section_name=1000
www.airbnb.com.au/rooms/1112833302463251442?adults=9&children=2&pets=1&search_mode=regular_search&check_in=2024-12-22&check_out=2024-12-28&source_impression_id=p3_1720094600_P3NtINEuiRiA5r4F&previous_page_section_name=1000

Process finished with exit code 0

